# Changing the color of Google Maps API marker labels after map initialization

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps API initialization function, where the Marker label color (for an array of markerPins) is set to `transparent`:

```
    markerPins[i] = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: position,
        map: map,
        optimized: false,
        icon: myPin,
        label: {
          color: 'transparent', // <= HERE
          fontSize: '11px',
          fontWeight: '900',
          text: 'Example Label'
        }
    });
```

This works. So far, so good.

At a later point (following a user action etc.) I would like to change the Marker label color.

I have written the following function:

```
// CHANGE MARKER LABEL COLOR
function changeMarkerLabelColor(labelColor) {

    for (let i = 0; i < markerPins.length; i++ ) {

        markerPins[i].label.color = labelColor;

    }
}
```

And it ***does work***. But seemingly only as the map is being initialised.

How is it possible to `get` and `set` the Marker label color *after* the map has initialized?

I am happy to deploy a javascript approach, a CSS approach, or any other approach - but I've been searching and testing and experimenting for hours and so far come up empty-handed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no documented `label` property of a marker.  Use the (documented) [`.setLabel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#Marker.setLabel) and [`.getLabel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#Marker.getLabel) functions:

```
function changeMarkerLabelColor(labelColor) {
  for (let i = 0; i < markerPins.length; i++ ) {
    var label = markerPins[i].getLabel();
    label.color = labelColor;
    markerPins[i].setLabel(label);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6fza3b0c/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map after setTimeout runs]

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  { position: {lat: 37.4419, lng: -122.1419}}, 
  { position: {lat: 37.4529598, lng: -122.1817252}},
  { position: {lat: 37.4688273, lng: -122.141075}},
  ];
var markerPins = [];

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    markerPins[i] = new google.maps.Marker({

      position: locations[i].position,
      map: map,
      optimized: false,
      label: {
        color: 'transparent', // <= HERE
        fontSize: '11px',
        fontWeight: '900',
        text: 'Example Label'
      }
    });
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    changeMarkerLabelColor("blue");
  }, 5000)
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function changeMarkerLabelColor(labelColor) {
  for (let i = 0; i < markerPins.length; i++) {
    var label = markerPins[i].getLabel();
    label.color = labelColor;
    markerPins[i].setLabel(label);

  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: You are exposing the API key

Comment: That isn't my key, it is a Google test key that works on StackOverflow